# Strange output when running assembly program

Tags: assembly, tasm

```
.model small
.stack

.data
intro db 10,13,"Inserisci un carattere: ",'$'
finale db 10,13,"Il carattere inserito e' una lettera maiuscola.",'$'
finale2 db 10,13,"Il carattere inserito e' una lettera minuscola.",'$'
finale3 db 10,13,"Il carattere inserito e' un carattere speciale.",'$' 
finale4 db 10,13,"Il carattere inserito e' una cifra numerica.",'$'
errore db 10,13,"Il carattere inserito non rientra nel range verificabile.",'$'
domanda db 10,13,"Inserire un nuovo carattere? [s/n]: ",'$'
var1 db ?
risp db ?

.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

start:

lea dx,intro
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov var1,al

cmp var1,32
JL errore1
cmp var1,125
JG errore1
cmp var1,47
JLE speciale
cmp var1,57
JLE numero
cmp var1,64
JLE speciale
cmp var1,90
JLE maiuscola
cmp var1,96
JLE speciale
cmp var1,122
JLE minuscola
cmp var1,125
JLE speciale


middle:
JMP start

maiuscola:
lea dx,finale
mov ah,09h
int 21h

jmp domanda1

minuscola:
lea dx,finale2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

jmp domanda1

speciale:
lea dx,finale3
mov ah,09h
int 21h

jmp domanda1

numero:
lea dx,finale4
mov ah,09h
int 21h

jmp domanda1

domanda1:
lea dx,domanda
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov risp,al

cmp risp,115
je middle
jmp fine

fine:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

errore1:
lea dx,errore
mov ah,09h
int 21h

JMP fine

end start
```

Using tasm and tlink returns no error but once I run it (using DosBox) the video output only shows strange ASCII symbols instead of text (intro,finale,finale2).
It was working just fine before I modified it in order to restart if user wants to/check the input...

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you should add a zero byte after each string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre DOS only requires strings to be **$** terminated when using the output function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last line should be

```
end
```

instead of

```
end start
```

Moreover, clear `ax` after `mov ds,ax`. 
I'd suggest writing a `main proc` would be better practice.

Comment: What would be the point of clearing `AX` after `MOV DS,AX` ? Care to explain?

Comment: Totally disagree that it's "good practice".  Bloating your code with useless instructions that set values that are overwritten without being read is a terrible idea.  It will make human readers wonder what they're missing, and waste time trying to find out where the value is used.  (Although hopefully not very much time, because you MOV to AH right away.)  Would otherwise upvote this answer for spotting the `end` vs. `end start` thing.